# Ampersand displayed as '&amp;' in XML document

Tags: php, xml, entities, ampersand

I'm having troubles with displaying the ampersand character inside a XML document, using PHP 5.6 (can't use PHP 7.x right now)

I tried using str_replace(), preg_replace and some other functions found here:
[Unable to Parse ampersand in PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153892/unable-to-parse-ampersand-in-php-string)

and here: [PHP not have a function for XML-safe entity decode? Not have some xml_entity_decode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039765/php-not-have-a-function-for-xml-safe-entity-decode-not-have-some-xml-entity-dec)

I've also noticed that ampersand character was a problem in PHP 5.2.x (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39521) although I think this has been fixed.

Here there are some example of what I tried to do:

```php
$string = "SOMETHING & OTHER THINGS";
$string = str_replace('&', '&amp;' $string);
$element = $domDocument->createElement('myElement', $string);
$rootElement->appendChild($element);
```

When I discovered about the bug I tried:

```php
$string = "SOMETHING & OTHER THINGS";
$string = str_replace('&', '&amp;' $string);
$element = $domDocument->createElement('myElement');
$element->appendChild( $domDocument->createTextNode($string) );
$rootElement->appendChild($element);
```

What I expected was:

```xml
<myElement>SOMETHING & OTHER THINGS</myElement>
```

What I got:

```xml
<myElement>SOMETHING &amp; OTHER THINGS</myElement>
```

Or sometimes:

```xml
<myElement/>
```

**EDIT: Maybe I should add that my software has to download the file. So when I open the xml file with Notepad++ i get the result that I shown up above.**

Can't really figure this thing out, any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: And what's the problem with this encoding?

Comment: That's the correct way to encode `&` in XML. `DOMDocument` does it automatically for you, you don't need to do anything special. When you parse the document it will be turned back into `&`.

Comment: The problem is that I need to display <myElement>SOMETHING & OTHER THINGS</myElement>

Not this: <myElement>SOMETHING &amp; OTHER THINGS</myElement>

Comment: @ChrisFederico: That's not a well-formed XML.

Comment: could you be a little more precise?

Comment: `<myElement>SOMETHING & OTHER THINGS</myElement>` is invalid XML that will cause XML parsers to throw an exception. Why are you trying to generate something that isn't XML using tools designed to generate XML?

Comment: So you are telling me that XML can't never display any node value containing & character?

Comment: @ChrisFederico — To express the character `&` as data in XML, the XML source code should include the sequence `&amp;`, which is what you have, which is what Barmar told you half an hour ago.

Comment: The only way you could put an actual `&` in there, was if you created a CDATA section.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem was that I actually opened the XML file with Notepad++, which showed the '&' entity instead of the ampersand character; opening the file in a XML parser "solved" my problem in a certain sense.

Thanks to Barmar (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) for making me notice this and to everyone that commented.

Answer (score 0):

1. `&` has to be encoded as `&amp;` for the XML to be valid.
2. XML Parsers will decode `&amp;` to `&`

The `&` has a special meaning in an XML string, just like `<`. It is used for entity references. This can be Unicode code points or named entities depending on the actual XML format. An example would be `&nbsp;` in (X)HTML. That is why `&` has to be encoded in most parts of an XML document. The XML serializer of the DOM extension does it for you and an XML parser will decode.